# Youtube API v3 get user name

Tags: php, youtube

I'm making requests (search) to the Youtube API v3. I can grab a lot of informations on videos I find, but I still miss the username (= the name of the uploader).

The thing is : **I can't find it on the ressource representation** (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search):

```
{


"kind": "youtube#searchResult",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": {
    "kind": string,
    "videoId": string,
    "channelId": string,
    "playlistId": string
  },
  "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": datetime,
    "channelId": string,
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "thumbnails": {
      (key): {
        "url": string,
        "width": unsigned integer,
        "height": unsigned integer
      }
    },
    "channelTitle": string,
    "liveBroadcastContent": string
  }
}
```

Any help ?